# How to limit the bandwidth/network rate for sshd per user?

Tags: networking, ubuntu, ssh, bandwidth, sftp

I have a computer set up as a server with Ubuntu 18.0.4 sharing with my friends, and using sftp to upload/download files. Recently one of my friends has been doing a large amount of transfer and occupy most of the bandwidth, thus I would like to limit his user's bandwidth through ssh. How can I get this done? Many thanks!

Comment: I don't think you can do it with user and SSH, but [it is likely possible per IP address](https://serverfault.com/questions/154451/throttle-bandwidth-via-iptables)

Answer (score 2):

#### Cooperative user

If the user is nice and cooperative, ask him or her to use an SFTP client with configurable speed limits (e.g. FileZilla). This may be the simplest solution.

[This answer of mine](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/671348/108618) provides a way to throttle an SSH connection performed by plain `ssh` in Linux. Since many tools (including CLI `sftp`) use `ssh` under the hood as transport, one just needs to put a line like

```
ProxyCommand pv -qL 20K | nc %h %p | pv -qL 10K
```

in their `~/.ssh/config` to limit each of them. With proper usage of `Match` the user will be able to limit their connections to your server only.

---

#### Not necessarily cooperative user

I understand you want a limiter that works on your server and does not rely on the user's will to cooperate. AFAIK a limiter similar to the client-side limiter from the linked answer cannot be applied to an arbitrary SSH connection on the server side. It can, however, be applied to data that flow through the `sftp` subsystem.

In your `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` there's a line like

```
Subsystem sftp internal-sftp
```

or

```
Subsystem sftp /usr/lib/sftp-server
```

We are going to use a wrapper over `sftp-server` to implement a limiter. Fortunately `sftp-server` communicates with `sshd` via standard streams. This makes our task of creating a wrapper relatively easy.

On the other hand `Subsystem` in `sshd_config` cannot be used under `Match`, it's a global setting. This means unfortunately we cannot use our wrapper for one user only. We will use it for any user and it will be the task of the wrapper to tell what user it runs under and act accordingly.

A basic wrapper may be like this:

```sh
#!/bin/sh

case "$USER" in
   abuser )
      pv -qL 20K | /usr/lib/sftp-server "$@" | pv -qL 10K
      ;;
   * )
      exec /usr/lib/sftp-server "$@"
      ;;
esac
```

The leftmost `pv` limits what flows from the client to your server; the rightmost `pv` limits what flows from your server to the client.

Now there's a problem: if `abuser` connects two or more times, each wrapper will limit its own bandwidth only. The user will be able to circumvent the limiter by transferring many files via many connections at once. I think limiting them as a pack is not easy (if possible at all), at least not within this method.

A useful solution is to detect if another wrapper for `abuser` works, deny any transfer if so. This will force `abuser` to use just one SFTP connection at a time and this connection will be properly limited.

To do so, act as root and create a directory (e.g.) `/sftp_wrapper`. Inside it create an empty regular file named `abuser.lockfile` and a script named `sftp-server-limited`. The directory and the script should be owned by `root:root` the lockfile should be owned by `abuser:root`. Make the mode for the directory `755`, `755` for the wrapper and `400` for the lockfile.

Assuming you're in `/sftp_wrapper` (important!) and you're root, the following shell code will set these things up (customize the `user=abuser` line before you paste the code):

```sh
user=abuser

chown root:root .
chmod 755 .

: > "$user".lockfile
chown "$user":root "$user".lockfile
chmod 400 "$user".lockfile

cat > sftp-server-limited << EOF
#!/bin/sh

case "\$USER" in
   $user )
      exec 9</sftp_wrapper/$user.lockfile
      flock -w 1 9 || exit 1
      pv -qL 20K | /usr/lib/sftp-server "\$@" | pv -qL 10K
      ;;
   * )
      exec /usr/lib/sftp-server "\$@"
      ;;
esac
EOF

chmod 755 sftp-server-limited
```

Now tell your `sshd` to use the wrapper instead of `sftp-server` or `internal-sftp`. In `sshd_config` find the `Subsystem sftp …` line and make it:

```
Subsystem sftp /sftp_wrapper/sftp-server-limited
```

Reload `sshd` by invoking:

```
systemctl reload sshd.service
```

Done.

---

#### Notes:

- In our `sftp-server-limited` I used quite low values for `pv -L`, so in tests it's quite obvious the method works. Adjust them to your needs.
- With such low values, if the client wants to interrupt the transfer (e.g. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> in interactive `sftp`) then they may have to wait several seconds until some buffers flush.
- Locking with `flock` is quite robust. The lock is released automatically when all processes with the descriptor created with `exec 9<…` exit. There is no need to unlock manually and there should be no stale lock, ever (unless there's a stale process).
- The script uses `case` and it can easily be extended to cover few more "special" users. For each such user you will need a separate lockfile though.
- Make sure `flock` and `pv` are installed.
- The wrapper applies only to the `sftp` subsystem.
- When limiting a user to just one SFTP connection at a time, note the connection may break for the user and until your server notices the fact, the user will not be able to connect again. Therefore it's nice to detect broken connections reasonably early. You can do this by setting quite low `ClientAlive*` values in `sshd_config` on the server. Example:

  ```
  ClientAliveInterval 15
  ClientAliveCountMax 4
  ```

  See [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/585887/108618) to learn what exactly these are for.