# is there any way to limit users' traffic usage in SSH

Tags: linux, networking, ubuntu, ssh

can we limit users' traffic usage in ssh?(For example User1 can only download/upload 1GB) i know ssh doesn't have this feature by default.
Is there any trick to do this?
Thanks for your help
my os is ubuntu

I read [this QA](https://superuser.com/questions/1432362/how-to-limit-the-bandwidth-network-rate-for-sshd-per-user?newreg=98bc1c6e08004dde93c925f17b3a97ec) but it limits the internet speed per second. i want internet usage limit.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Superuser . Download files onto the machine or download files from the machine using SSH itself (SCP?)?

Comment: Hi, thatnks for your reply. i use it as a proxy by tunneling my http[s] traffic into ssh.

Comment: I did some tests with nftables. OpenSSH uses privilege separation, and even if the ssh network activity is done by the sshd sub-process belonging to the actual user, there's also a monitoring sshd process belonging to root sharing the same socket, and nftables' skuid will always match this process as socket owner (root = 0) instead of the process doing the actual traffic. So it looks like this accounting on the ssh flow can't be dealt with nftables (nor probably iptables for the same reason). There should still be accounting on the https flow possible. Depends on what OP wants to measure.